# time compexity of my algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm having trouble with finding the O-time of some algoritms. I've searched quite some O notations but whenever my excercise gets harder, I can't find the solution. Now I came across an algoritm and I can't really find a solution.
I've searched through Stack Overflow but found nothing to really help me. The best post I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm/). 
It only said what I knew and not really how to calculate it or see it. Also the second post did say some algoritms with solutions, but not how to find it.

**The Code**

```
`for i = 1; i <= n; i++
    for j = 1; j <= i; j++
        for k = 1; k <= i; k++
            x = x + 1
`
```

**Question**

What is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Also, are there some good tutorials to help me understand this matter better?

Also sorry if there's a stack overflow post of this allready but I couldn't find a good one to help me.

Comment: Your last for loop increments `j`, not `k`, so the loop is infinite

Comment: I'm sorry that was a mistype from me, I edditted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The loop defining `i` runs `n` times.
- The loop defining `j` runs `n * n/2` times
- The loop defining `k` runs `n * n/2 * n/2` times

`= n * 1/2 * n * 1/2 * n`

`= n * n * n * 1/2 * 1/2`

`= O(n^3)`

You can also try to infer that from the final value of the variable `x`, which should be roughly proportional to `n^3`